# Run a XAML method (Not BindingContext)

Tags: xamarin, .net-6.0, maui, .net-7.0

In a XAML file, I would like to Invoke a method of some class (Not the bindingContext or C# code behind linked to said XAML). The class can then return an instance of a transient or a singleton service, in my case a viewModel.

XAML :

```
 BindingContext="{custom:XAMLServiceHelper {viewModel:HomePageViewModel}}"
```

Class:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(ViewModel))]
public class XAMLServiceHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the path.
    /// </summary>
    public object ViewModel { get; set; }

    public XAMLServiceHelper()
    {

    }

    public XAMLServiceHelper(object viewModel)
    {

    }

    public object GetViewModel(object viewModel)
    {
       return ServiceProvider.GetService<viewModel>();
    }
}
```

I know I am missing quite a bit, but I am not sure if it is at all possible.

I know something similar although still quite different is possible for converting strings. I was wondering if there was something I would need to inherit.

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{custom:FileImage myImage.png}"/>
```

Class:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Path))]
public class FileImageExtension : IMarkupExtension<FileImageSource>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the path.
    /// </summary>
    public string Path { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert to file image source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">path.</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="FileImageSource"/>FileImageSource.</returns>
    public static FileImageSource Convert(string path)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI)
        {
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine("Assets/", path);
        }

        return (FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile(path);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide value to the file image source provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider">serviceProvider.</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="ServiceProvider"/>serviceProvider.</returns>
    public FileImageSource ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Convert(this.Path);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get provider value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider">serviceProvider.</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="ProvideValue"/>provideValue.</returns>
    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: *"Run a XAML method"* and *"...a class inside of a XAML file"* led me to think you were trying to access a class that was inside a XAML file (whatever that would mean). Reading further, I realize you mean "In XAML, Invoke a method of some class." and "(reach out to a class) (FROM inside a XAML file)" Just saying this, in case anyone else has similar confusion on reading this.

Comment: Sorry about that, Is that better?

Comment: Seems what you want is [Create XAML markup extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/markup-extensions/create?view=net-maui-7.0) ?